# Subsetting a data frame on multiple vectors/lists and applying a function for each subset combination in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, lapply, sapply

I have a data frame (df) that contains multiple columns like items, companies, region, date, price. I want to apply some function or transformation such as add the mean of prices to the price column for each subset using the combination/groupings from the 3 vectors below to subset my data frame before applying the function. The three vectors contain distinct items, companies, and regions from the data frame and also have different lengths as well, i.e. there more distinct items than companies or regions for example.

Example of the data frame:

```
Date | Region | Company | Item | Price
---------------------------------------
7/16 | NW     | ABC     | Phone| 200
8/16 | NW     | ABC     | Phone| 200
8/16 | SW     | DEF     | Food | 100
8/16 | SW     | DEF     | Food | 50
9/16 | NW     | ABC     | Tools| 100
9/16 | NW     | DEF     | Tools| 50
```

3 Vectors below:

```
item <- unique(df$item) # 3 different items
company <- unique(df$company) # 2 different companies
region <- unique(df$region) # 2 regions
```

I was thinking about running a nested for loop and apply a function within the the loop. It seems really inefficient and on top of that I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

The for loop I imagined would go something like this...

```
for (i in seq_along(item))
{
  for (j in seq_along(company))
  {
    for (k in seq_along(region))
    {
      x <- df[df$item==i & df$company==j & df$region==k,]
      x$Price <- x$Price + mean(x$Price)
      return(x)
    }
  }
}
```

The output I'm looking for is like this as a result of each grouping and adding the mean price of the group to the price column of the df:

```
Date | Region | Company | Item | Price
---------------------------------------
7/16 | NW     | ABC     | Phone| 400
8/16 | NW     | ABC     | Phone| 400
8/16 | SW     | DEF     | Food | 175
8/16 | SW     | DEF     | Food | 125
9/16 | NW     | ABC     | Tools| 200
9/16 | NW     | DEF     | Tools| 100
```

Is there a better way to do this? Either a better for loop or some sapply or lapply method? I'm not sure how to approach this since the 3 vectors have varying lengths.

Comment: It is too broad. Please provide a reproducible example of your data frame and the function.

Comment: `by(df, list(df$item, df$company, df$region), somefunc)` or perhaps the tidyverse with `dplyr:;group_by(df, item, company, region) %>% ...`.

Comment: Added the example data frame and function I want to apply as well as the desired output!

Comment: for-loops are easily avoided in R:  I advise you to learn about `dplyr` and its `group_by` feature.

Comment: The duplicate I've just flagged is about `sum` instead of `mean`, but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`group_by` and `mutate` will do the trick!

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data_frame(
  Date = c("7/16","8/16","8/16","8/16","9/16","9/16"),
  Region = c("NW", "NW", "SW", "SW", "NW", "NW"),
  Company = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "ABC", "DEF"),
  Item = c("Phone", "Phone", "Food", "Food", "Tools", "Tools"),
  Price = c(200, 200, 100, 50, 100, 50)
  )

data %>% 
  group_by(Region, Company, Item) %>% 
  mutate(Price = Price + mean(Price))
```

Output looks like:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: Region, Company, Item [4]
   Date Region Company  Item Price
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1  7/16     NW     ABC Phone   400
2  8/16     NW     ABC Phone   400
3  8/16     SW     DEF  Food   175
4  8/16     SW     DEF  Food   125
5  9/16     NW     ABC Tools   200
6  9/16     NW     DEF Tools   100
```

Comment: If you need a more complicated function than just Price + mean(Price), you can use by_slice from `dpurrrlyr` library or write your own function and feed it into the `mutate`, or `summarise` if you are trying to get distinct groups.

Comment: Thanks this looks awesome! Would it be possible to feed in a very complicated function that does something like outlier trimming into `mutate` or is it more advisable to use `by_slice`?

Comment: Yep, just define your function and then call it from the mutate. Note that when you call a df's var in mutate it will come in as a *vector* that is the length of your grouping.